# package self running android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

for demonstration purpose of a developed Android App I would like to distribute a "Self running android emulator" with my App installed to some people. It should be simple for them to start the emulator on their computer and work with my App.

Currently I have to prepare their computer with the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" and my prepared virtual device (in their home directory). I wonder if there is a smarter solution.

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of anything that offers this today. If you build such a thing from the Android SDK components, spread the word of the recipe!

Comment: If you don't know it - who else could? Thank's for the moment - I will leave this question open a while but I am quite sure you will earn the accepted points.

Comment: @K. Claszen: "If you don't know it - who else could?" -- well, I certainly don't have the whole Android ecosystem memorized. :-) In theory, it shouldn't be that tough: identify the necessary bits of the SDK and create your own installer that also sets up the canned AVD in the right spot. I just haven't seen anyone do it, let alone write up the various steps. Given that the Android Tools team is working in the open, there's a reasonable chance that one could get a bit of help, in terms of information, from Google itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete packaged solution. I am going to see if I can update the version it is running. http://www.redmondpie.com/android-emulator-for-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the [BlueStacks App Player](http://bluestacks.com) is that what I am looking for. Did not test it yet but will give it a try if needed.